# Errors with Akka-Typed Java

Tags: java, error-handling, akka, akka-typed

The Akka documentation makes a distinction between *validation error* and *failure*. But, while there is a complete chapter on failure, I did not see much on validation error.

> A validation error means that the data of a command sent to an actor is not valid, this should rather be modelled as a part of the actor protocol than make the actor throw exceptions.
>
> -- https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/fault-tolerance.html

I searched a bit but still was not able to find much information on that subject. At this time, I see two options;

### Option 1, type hierarchy:

We can use a type hierarchy to have a typed structure an link between a command, his successful answer and errors:

```
class MyCommand { 
   ActorRef<MyCommandAnswer> replyTo;
   // .. 
}
interface MyCommandAnswer { }
class MyCommandSuccess implements MyCommandAnswer { /* .. */ }
class MyCommandError implements MyCommandAnswer { /* .. */ }
```

The nice thing is that there is a strong relationship between the command and the two possibles case of answers.

However, this is verbose and the type of answer is not obvious (we have to read the type hierarchy to discover possible types). Moreover, the answer must be handled with `instanceof` or a visitor like pattern (that will not reduce the verbosity)

### Option 2, an `Either` like

Scala has an `Either` type that can be `Left` or `Right`. `Left` is usually holding an error while the `Right` side contains a success. There is also `Try` that use the same pattern.

> Represents a value of one of two possible types (a disjoint union). An instance of Either is an instance of either scala.util.Left or scala.util.Right.
>
> -- https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/util/Either.html

We can create a similar type that will be replied by our actors.

```
abstract class Either<L, R> {
  public static <L> Either<L, ?> left(L error) {
    return new Left(error);
  }
  public static <R> Either<?, R> right(R value) {
    return new Right(value);
  }

  public abstract boolean isLeft();
  public abstract boolean isRight();
  public abstract <O> Either<L, O> map(Function<R, O> mapping);
  public abstract <O> O orElse(Supplier<O> other);
  // ...
}


class MyCommand {
  ActorRef<Either<MyCommandError, MyCommandSuccess>> replyTo;
  // ..
}
```

The good thing is that we always know the possible answer and the `Either` class can be reused across all actors. Which makes the usage easier in the project. We can have many methods of that type to deal with the two cases and do not have to duplicate the code for all commands.

This a bit of functionally inspired code that may not be natural to everyone.

---

My preference is obviously for the `Either` type. But I would like to have the knowledge of the community on that topic.

So, my question is, *how did you manage errors with Akka-typed and Java ?*

Thanks

Comment: Coming from Scala, the `Either` approach is generally what I'd tend to prefer.

Comment: @LeviRamsey indeed, me too. But this will be a Java project so I would like to know the usages for that community. I am a bit astonished about the lack of information on that subject.

Comment: The idiomatic encoding of something like an Algebraic Data Type, which is what this wants to be, in Java is probably the `interface` with extending classes (it's not exact because Java won't enforce `sealed`ness).  `Either` is in many ways superior (though again, not being `sealed` might be something to worry about), but probably not idiomatic.  The golangish pattern of "an A and a B, possibly null" creeping into Java (see the Java API for the ask pattern in Akka for an example), which is kind of sad...

Answer (score 2):

`StatusReply` is intended as a good encoding of success/error responses for actor protocols, see docs: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/interaction-patterns.html#generic-response-wrapper